# Polymer - Make the parent element wait until child element completes execution

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I have a element called `parent-element` with a property called `name`.

`parent-element` has a child element called `child-element`.
Both have a two way bound property called `name`

Adding a code snippet to explain what I told above

```
<parent-element>
  <template>
    <child-element name={{name}}> </child-element>
  </template>
 <script>
   properties: {
    name: String
    }
 </script>
</parent-element>
```

My Issue:

I want `parent-element` to wait until `child-element` executes and sends back the property `name` (or) at least the `parent-element` must re-render after each time `child-element` sends new value for `name` property.

Is there any example on how to do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should mark `notify` as true in your child element and add observer on `name` property in your parent element. This way whenever property in child element changes your parent will be notified.
Please note you'll need to do a two-way binding from parent to child for it to work.
If you don't want parent to update child's property mark child's `name`
 property as `readOnly`

```html
<script src="https://polygit.org/components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="https://polygit.org/components/polymer/polymer.html">

<dom-module id="child-element">
  <template></template>
</dom-module>
<script>
  Polymer({
    is: 'child-element',
    properties: {
      name: {
        type: String,
        notify: true
      }
    },
    attached: function() {
      this.name = "John";
    }
  });
</script>



<dom-module id="parent-element">
  <template>
    [[name]]
    <child-element name="{{name}}"></child-element>
  </template>
</dom-module>
<script>
  Polymer({
    is: 'parent-element',
    properties: {
      name: {
        type: String,
        value: "James",
        observer: '_nameChanged'
      }
    },
    _nameChanged: function(newVal) {
      console.log("Name is", this.name);
    }
  });
</script>

<parent-element></parent-element>
```